# How to load in new messages from JSON with fixed amount of entries using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I’m hosting a chatting application. Server-side I’m storing messages in JSON. (Example: `[{"message":"Hey!","time":1549087762},{"message":"What’s up?","time":1549087763}]`) When sending messages I’m shifting off the oldest entry if json.messages count is greater than 10. So to summarize this, there are only 10 messages shown at a time.

I am having trouble displaying new messages after a chat room reaches 10 messages due to number incrementing logic.

```
function loadMessages() {
  var myRequest = new Request('https://console.chat/api/read.php?domain=' + domain);
  fetch(myRequest)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++) {
        var time = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        if (data.messages[i].time < time) {
          console.log(data.messages[i].message);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

In my code example I am attempting to accomplish this and failed. I have also tried setting the index to 9 so that it keeps adding. No matter what, once a chat reaches 10 messages it won’t output new ones anymore or will spam the chat with the messages endlessly. Obvious solutions aside: the messages are saving properly server side that’s not the issue.

Comment: I ran it with some mock data and it seems to run fine. It just prints all messages. Do you want to do the shifting thing in the frontend maybe?

https://jsfiddle.net/7tzaxyw6/3/

Comment: If you show your backend code, it may be easier to work out how to only pass the last 10 messages back.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the last 10 elements of the `messages` array you can do it like this

```
.then(function(data) {
  data.messages = data.messages.slice(Math.max(data.messages.length - 10, 0))

  for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++) {
    var time = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    if (data.messages[i].time < time) {
      console.log(data.messages[i].message);
    }
  }
});
```

Although it would be wiser to do this in the backend.

Comment: Yeah the backend PHP is only storing 10 messages. It’s the JavaScript that’s having problems

Comment: It shows all messages like expected, but with setInterval it spams Chat.

Comment: Where is the `setIntrerval`?